# Calculate the differential of $\mathbb{R}^3$ function

Tags: analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative, vector-fields

I want to calculate the differential of the function $F:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, $$F(r, \theta, \phi)=\left (r\sin \left (\theta\right )\cos \left (\phi \right ),  r\sin \left (\theta\right )\sin \left (\phi \right ), r\cos \left (\theta\right )\right )$$ For that do we have to calculate the Jacobi matrix? Or how is in this case the differential defined?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that a vector field has a specific 'differential', not as simply as 1-dimensional functions anyway.
You can find for example the partial derivatives of it with respect to each of the 3 variables or you can find the $\mathit{divergence}$ of the field, both are related to derivatives.

This article goes into more detail about things like "total derivatives" and more if that's what you mean.
[Meaning of derivatives of vector fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195000/meaning-of-derivatives-of-vector-fields)

Comment: What about the notions of "total differential", "Fréchet derivative", etc.?

Comment: I was just giving some examples if we are talking about more basic operations, the article I tagged talked about total differentials and more

Comment: So the total differential is the Jacobi matrix for such a function, or not?

Comment: There are similar in their calculation but the total differential is dependent on a basis and it is a linear map